# About sign of tan

Tags: calculus

Let x,y are cartesian coordinates of point and $\phi\\$ is polar angle.
$$\begin{array}{l}\tan \phi  = y/x = dy/dx\\\phi  = \arctan \left( {y/x} \right)\\\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial x}} =  - \frac{y}{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}\\\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial y}} = \frac{x}{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}\\\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial x}}/\frac{{\partial \phi }}{{\partial y}} = \frac{{\partial y}}{{\partial x}} =  - \frac{y}{x} \ne \tan \phi \end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaebbnrfifHhDYfgasaacH8srps0l
% bbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9q8WqFfea0-yr0R
% Yxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8GqFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaaeWabaWaaaGceaqabeaaciGG0bGaaiyyaiaac6gacqaHvp
% GzcqGH9aqpcaWG5bGaai4laiaadIhacqGH9aqpcaWGKbGaamyEaiaa
% c+cacaWGKbGaamiEaaqaaiabew9aMjabg2da9iGacggacaGGYbGaai
% 4yaiaacshacaGGHbGaaiOBamaabmaabaGaamyEaiaac+cacaWG4baa
% caGLOaGaayzkaaaabaWaaSaaaeaacqGHciITcqaHvpGzaeaacqGHci
% ITcaWG4baaaiabg2da9iabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaamyEaaqaaiaadIha
% daahaaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaWG5bWaaWbaaSqabeaaca
% aIYaaaaaaaaOqaamaalaaabaGaeyOaIyRaeqy1dygabaGaeyOaIyRa
% amyEaaaacqGH9aqpdaWcaaqaaiaadIhaaeaacaWG4bWaaWbaaSqabe
% aacaaIYaaaaOGaey4kaSIaamyEamaaCaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaaaaaa
% keaadaWcaaqaaiabgkGi2kabew9aMbqaaiabgkGi2kaadIhaaaGaai
% 4lamaalaaabaGaeyOaIyRaeqy1dygabaGaeyOaIyRaamyEaaaacqGH
% 9aqpdaWcaaqaaiabgkGi2kaadMhaaeaacqGHciITcaWG4baaaiabg2
% da9iabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaamyEaaqaaiaadIhaaaGaeyiyIKRaciiD
% aiaacggacaGGUbGaeqy1dygaaaa!8217!
$$
What's is wrong?Why I've got an opposite sign?

Comment: Where do you get the $\frac yx = \frac {dy}{dx}$ in the first line?

Comment: I agree with you Ross, I understood my mistake$$y/x \ne dy/dx
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaebbnrfifHhDYfgasaacH8srps0l
% bbf9q8WrFfeuY-Hhbbf9v8qqaqFr0xc9pk0xbba9q8WqFfea0-yr0R
% Yxir-Jbba9q8aq0-yq-He9q8GqFr0xfr-xfr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGa
% aiaabeqaaeWabaWaaaGcbaGaamyEaiaac+cacaWG4bGaeyiyIKRaam
% izaiaadMhacaGGVaGaamizaiaadIhaaaa!3A89!
$$
When I give dx I reduce &//phi&